# awk or sed , whichever is more apt

Tags: unix, awk

reading a csv file in unix and, doing some substitution on some of the columns. like 2nd column(string type) should be replaced by value of (2nd column itself + value of the 1st column(integer)), then 5th column by $5+$4 and so on.
Below is the sample I/O. and the first line which is Description must be left as is .

sample Input

```
EmpID|Empname|Empadd|roleId|roleDesc|Dept 
100|mst|Del|20|SD|DA 
101|ms|Del|21|XS|DA
```

Sample output

```
EmpID|Empname|Empadd|roleId|roleDesc|Dept 
100|mst100|Del|20|SD20|DA
101|ms101|Del|21|XS21|DA
```

empname has been concatenated with empid & the role desc with roleID.

Comment: `awk` is quite good for that task. Show the `awk` script that you have tried...

Comment: `Hope that's helpful :)`  for the assignment?

Comment: awk 'NR>1, FS=OFS="|"{
 $2=$2$1; $5=$5$4 ; print}'file.csv > file.csv 

I must mention that I'm a newbie in unix & this is the first time I'm trying a combat with awk

Comment: @devnull : I meant that for the sample data

Comment: It's been a whole hour and nobody's made an `apt-get` joke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it almost right, this works:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} (NR>1) {$2=$2 "" $1; $5=$5 "" $4} {print}' <<EOF                                           
EmpID|Empname|Empadd|roleId|roleDesc|Dept
100|mst|Del|20|SD|DA
101|ms|Del|21|XS|DA
EOF
=>
  EmpID|Empname|Empadd|roleId|roleDesc|Dept 
  100|mst100|Del|20|SD20|DA 
  101|ms101|Del|21|XS21|DA
```

Comment: will the same thing work fine on .dat file as well ?

Comment: If by .dat file you mean a binary format of some sort, no.  Reason is awk is strictly line and column oriented, i.e. you must have `\n` in there so awk can focus on a line at a time, then this line is split down into columns using the `FS` (field separator)

Comment: no binary format, the data pattern is exactly similar to the above mentioned format of csv file

Comment: oh you mean the file suffix is just .dat instead of .csv?  Yes, that doesn't matter, awk will *assume* you pass it files it can handle, i.e. they are made up of FS (field separator) and RS (record separator, typically \n)

Comment: yep, it's just the file extension as far as I know , which differs.

Comment: @hroptatyr awk is record oriented, not line oriented. You do not need `\n`s in your file - just set `RS` appropriately for whatever separates your records.

Comment: @mst UNIX tools pay absolutely no notice of file extensions like `.csv` or `.dat` and treat files without extensions exactly the same as files with extensions. UNIX tools assume you know what you're doing and invoke them on file contents they are designed to work on. There are UNIX tools that can analyze file contents to figure out what they are (e.g. `man file`) if you ever need to find out what sort of content is within a file.

Comment: trying to skip last line for the same file and getting syntax error 

this is what I tried 
$ awk -v TR=`wc -l<inputfile 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} (NR>1 && NR<TR) {$2=$2 "" $1; $5=$5 "" $4} {print}' <<EOF Suggestions ??

Comment: It does work here, are you sure you want to put a `here-document` to awk? why not do `awk -v TR=$(wc -l inputfile) {all the awk code} inputfile`?

Answer (score 0):

```
> awk -F"|" -v OFS="|" 'NR!=1{$2=$1$2&&$5=$5$4}1' temp
EmpID|Empname|Empadd|roleId|roleDesc|Dept
100|1|Del|20|SD20|DA
101|1|Del|21|XS21|DA
>
```